# Java Regex - Get all words before substring in String

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have a string which contains a sentence and I want to split it in half, based on a word.
I have the regex `(\\w+) word` which I thought would get me all the words before "word" + "word" itself, then I could just remove the last four chars.

However this doesn't seem to work.. any ideas what I've done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: code is more helpful then describing the problem.

Comment: Maybe consider a non-greedy qualifier '+?' instead of '+'

Comment: "This doesn't seem to work," huh? What happens? What do you want to happen?

Comment: why not just use word? Using Pattern.find you can find its index in a string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\s]+) word");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("Could you test a phrase with some word");
        while (m.find()) {
            System.err.println(m.group(1));
            System.err.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using string manipulation:

```
int idx = sentence.indexOf(word);
if (idx < 0)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Word not found.");
String before = sentence.substring(0, idx);
```

Using regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(word));
Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
if (!m.find())
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Word not found.");
String before = sentence.substring(0, m.start());
```

Alternatively:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(word) + ".*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
if (!m.matches())
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Word not found.");
String before = m.group(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You will want to tokenize each part of the sentence before and after the word.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/

```
 String[] result = "this is a test".split("\\s"); //replace \\s with your word
 for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
     System.out.println(result[x]);
```

Comment: I could help expand on my example if need be, but a quick over view is that the sections of the sentence are stored in an array, and it's split by the word you have breaking the sentence up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?(?= word)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("Everything before the word");
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

It breaks down as follows:

.*? everything

(?= before

*word*

) end

Comment: Oh yeah, silly attempt sums it up nicely :) I'm not being rude here, I'm telling a fact...

Comment: I don't see how code format is necessary since the question was regarding the regular expression itself, I would assume he already knows how to compile an expression. I gave the expression and broke it apart to show what each section is doing. I'll try to be more descriptive in the future, brand new to stack overflow.

Comment: Your edit is already a lot better, I've cleared the downvote. Have fun on SO!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `+` is a greedy quantifier and will match the entire String **including** the word you specify, without giving back.

If you change it to `(\\w+?) word` it should work (reluctant quantifier). More on quantifiers and their exact function [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

Comment: `+` is greedy, but it *does* allow backtracking. The possessive equivalent is `++`

Comment: Okay, I've never really figured quantifiers out then. I think by backtracking you mean that you actually specify where and what in the regex? Whereas, reluctant will find 2 matches automatically, given that the input string contains the `word` he was looking for...

Comment: By backtracking I mean that the expression "\\w+\\w" will match "xy". The matcher will match "\\w+" against "xy", then realize that there is nothing left to match the second "\\w" against. So it will backtrack, matching "\\w+" against "x", and the second "\\w" against "y".